# Override using the .groups argument

Tags: r

Below is my R code, and this is the message I am receiving summarise()`has grouped output by 'member_casual'. You can override using the`.groups` argument.

```
> all_trips_v2 %>% 
+   mutate(weekday = wday(started_at, label = TRUE)) %>% 
+   group_by(member_casual, weekday) %>% 
+   summarise(number_of_rides = n()
+             ,average_duration = mean(ride_length)) %>% 
+   arrange(member_casual, weekday)  %>% 
+   ggplot(aes(x = weekday, y = number_of_rides, fill = member_casual)) +
+   geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

I have seen that this is a friendly message, however I am not getting the output I am looking for. It doesn't seem to be grouping by weekday. How can I use the .groups argument to fix this?

Below are the first 3 rows of my dataset

```
structure(list(ride_id = c("F96D5A74A3E41399", "13CB7EB698CEDB88", 
"BD88A2E670661CE5"), rideable_type = c("electric_bike", "classic_bike", 
"electric_bike"), started_at = c("1/21/2023 20:05", "1/10/2023 15:37", 
"1/2/2023 7:51"), ended_at = c("1/21/2023 20:16", "1/10/2023 15:46", 
"1/2/2023 8:05"), start_station_name = c("Lincoln Ave & Fullerton Ave", 
"Kimbark Ave & 53rd St", "Western Ave & Lunt Ave"), start_station_id = c("TA1309000058", 
"TA1309000037", "RP-005"), end_station_name = c("Hampden Ct & Diversey Ave", 
"Greenwood Ave & 47th St", "Valli Produce - Evanston Plaza"), 
    end_station_id = c("202480", "TA1308000002", "599"), member_casual = c("member", 
    "member", "casual"), ride_length = c(653, 511, 796), day_of_week = c("Saturday", 
    "Tuesday", "Monday"), date = structure(c(19378, 19367, 19359
    ), class = "Date"), month = c("01", "01", "01"), day = c("21", 
    "10", "02"), year = c("2023", "2023", "2023")), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! To silent the warning about `.groups` try `summarise(..., .groups = "drop")`. However, the issue with your plot is most likely not related to `.groups`. Looks more as if something went wrong when creating your `weekday` variable. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data best shared via `dput()`.

Comment: @stefan Thank you! I appreciate the help, I went ahead and posted the first 3 rows of my dataset, forgive me if this isn't quite right it was my first time using dput(). Let me know if I can provide anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't reproduce your issue. Instead I get an error

> character string is not in a standard unambiguous format.

when I run your code. Anyway, to fix the error (and most likely also your issue) we have to set the date `format` when converting `started_at` to a date or datetime. Afterwards `wday()` should assign the proper weekday and give your a nice plot with the counts per weekday:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

all_trips_v2 %>%
  mutate(
    # Convert to proper dates
    started_at = as_date(started_at, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"),
    weekday = wday(started_at, label = TRUE)
  ) %>%
  group_by(member_casual, weekday) %>%
  summarise(
    number_of_rides = n(),
    average_duration = mean(ride_length),
    .groups = "drop"
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = weekday, y = number_of_rides, fill = member_casual)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That completely solved it. You just saved a beginner a lot of headache.